# How to open .cshtml in designer view?

Tags: view, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to design a view using asp.net mvc 3 RC. I am not sure but I am not able to open my cshtml files in designer mode. I can just change their source html but no design time assistance is there.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: There is at least the "Page Inspector". Right-click on the cshtml in the solution explorer and select "Page Inspector".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any graphical designer for ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622969/is-there-any-graphical-designer-for-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this version the CSHTML editor does not support a designer view. Sorry.

Comment: Will razor view be designer supported going further (MVC 3) ?

Comment: I've gone further but still can't see one; not even in MVC 4.  I'll keep going.