# How to view cshtml page in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP 1. On opening/creating any .cshtml page (view), I am unable to find the option to see the rendered page in VS as soon as I make any change (similar to "design" tab in web-forms).

Is this not supported in VS 2010 or am I missing something?

Comment: design tab aka Design view doesn't work for Razor files (in .cshtml extension files).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any graphical designer for ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622969/is-there-any-graphical-designer-for-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The design view doesn't exist in MVC projects.

Take a look at this answer for more information: [Is there any graphical designer for ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622969/is-there-any-graphical-designer-for-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 6):

If you need the visual assistance when designing, you can run your application without debugging ( Ctrl - F5 ), and then once updates are made, you can refresh the web browser to view updates. It isn't real-time, but at least it is something.

Comment: This isn't recommended, since the debugger is pretty necessary when developing new apps.

Answer (score -1):

In visual studio 2019 you can use the option "Show in browser" or click CTRL + SHIFT + W

Comment: This does not work for ASP pages, since the webiste needs to be running locally